# libcamera is missing in Ubuntu aarch 64, raspberry pi

Tags: software-installation

I installed picamera2 on raspberry pi using ubuntu arch 64 bit. However, I face this error, when I import picamera2. It seems the problem only occurs on raspberry pi.

```
>>> import picamera2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ahmad/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/picamera2/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .configuration import CameraConfiguration, StreamConfiguration
  File "/home/ahmad/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/picamera2/configuration.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .controls import Controls
  File "/home/ahmad/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/picamera2/controls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from libcamera import ControlType, Size, Rectangle
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libcamera'
```

Any suggestion please?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and why may help as well. I find it impossible to follow what it is you are asking.

Comment: Have you install that app? See this site. https://www.arducam.com/docs/cameras-for-raspberry-pi/what-is-libcamera/

Comment: Thank you @David, I installed picamera2 to capture pictures using raspberry pi, however when I run python code it is complain about libcamera, it is not installed on ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: So I guess the fix is to install it.

Comment: Hi @David, the link that you shared, showed this message:
Cannot find the corresponding package, please send the following information to support@arducam.com Hardware Revision: c03114
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-1012-raspi
Package: libcamera_dev -- Jammy Jellyfish-arm64

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on https://libcamera.org/getting-started.html

---

First, install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt install build-essential meson ninja libyaml-dev python3-yaml python3-ply python3-jinja2 libssl-dev openssl git
```

Then, download the source code,

```
git clone https://git.libcamera.org/libcamera/libcamera.git
```

Go to the directory,

```
cd libcamera
```

And compile.

```
meson build
sudo ninja -C build install
```

Comment: I installed libcamera using this command: sudo apt install libcamera-dev however, this error still there: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libcamera'. Could you please suggest any idea? I am using python3.10.6

Comment: When I run this command sudo apt install libcamera-dev, I tried to run libcamera-hello,however its not working, I got libcamera-hello: command not found. I believe the previous command did not install all dependencies.

Comment: @AhmadAlhonainy I have edited the answer